# Adobe Flex/Air ServerSocket: remote connection from Socket class

Tags: android, apache-flex, flex4.5, socketserver

I have to ask this because Flash/Flex is driving me nuts.

I am using the ServerSocket class in an Air environment on the desktop to setup a server that listens for mobile clients (Air for mobile). I tested this in debug mode (Flash Builder) and everything worked fine: ServerSocket to listen to 127.0.0.1:8889 (local machine) --> Connection to 127.0.0.1, port 8889 setup on the mobile (local machine) --> check.

So I installed the app on my android smartphone (WiFi connected) and entered the machines IP and port but I couldn't get connected: ServerSocket to listen to 127.0.0.1:8889 (local machine) --> Connection to 192.168.2.101, port 8889 setup on the mobile --> not working.

Just for testing I setup an easy Java server, connected to the Java SocketServer and voilà it worked. So I assume that the problem lies within the SocketServer class of the Air environment.

Do you have any ideas? Would be glad if you guys could help.

Happy new year!

Comment: There is some small progress but I can't figure out how to solve this. Apparently the problem comes from the different namespaces.

The Java server shows up in the listening ports as `*:8888`. In contrary the Air server calls himself `ereg.adobe.com:4321`. I suppose that means that only connection from the domain `ereg.adobe.com` are accepted. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

1) You can verify with "netstat" command on Windows/Linux that your server is indeed listening at the port. Can you telnet to that port from another machine, using PuTTy or native "telnet"? Does you firewall (on Windows/Linux, doesn't matter) allow connections to that port?

2) Do you handle **socket policy** requests? For example with [my Perl script or my Apache module](http://code.google.com/p/mod-socket-policy/source/browse/#svn/trunk) (the script will run on Windows/Linux).

Good luck :-) I run [a small multiplayer card game](http://apps.facebook.com/video-preferans/) in Flex + Perl and had to take many hurdles...

Answer (score 0):

ServerSocket is not supported on mobile.